# while loop not progressing to next iteration

Tags: python

My problem is with the `try` statement in the below code. I am pulling data within range from monthly data files and outputting them to a consolidated file for Power BI to read from.

An issue that can occur is if an engineer has the consolidated file open, I will get a permission error when attempting to write to this file. My solution was to try 5 times. If it fails all 5 times, ignore writing the file and they will need to wait until the next time this script runs to get updated data, their punishment for leaving it open.

```
#=================================================================================
# Create the consolidated file that power BI will use
#=================================================================================
def createDashboardFile(self):
    outputData = pd.DataFrame(columns=consolidatedHeaders)
    rangeStart = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=-self.dashboardRange)
    months = (datetime.datetime.today().month - rangeStart.month) + 1
    for month in range(0,months):
        path=self.consolidatedPath + r'\\' + str(rangeStart.year) + str(('00' + str(rangeStart.month))[-2:]) + '.csv'
        if os.path.exists(path):
            inputData = pd.read_csv(path)
            inputData.columns = inputData.columns.str.strip()
            inputData['Timestamp']= pd.to_datetime(inputData['Timestamp'])
            inScope = inputData['Timestamp'] >= rangeStart
            #Remove rows where the date is not in range
            inputData = inputData[inScope]
            outputData = outputData.append(inputData, ignore_index=True)
            rangeStart = rangeStart.replace(day=1)
            rangeStart = rangeStart + datetime.timedelta(days=32)
            rangeStart = rangeStart.replace(day=1)
    tryCount = 0
    while tryCount < 5:
        try:
            with open(self.biFile, 'w') as o:
                outputData.to_csv(o, header=True, index=False)
            tryCount = 5
        except:
            tryCount = tryCount =+ 1
            if tryCount < 5:
                logEvent('BI File Write Error #'+ str(tryCount) + ', ' + os.path.basename(self.biFile), False)
            else:
                logEvent('BI File Write Failed, ' + os.path.basename(self.biFile), False)
```

The problem is the code loops at `tryCount = 1` and will infinitely loop until it successfully writes. What have I done wrong in the `try` statement? Or, for extra credit, is there a better way of handling trying to write to a file that someone has left open?

```
BI File Write Error #1, Makino.csv
BI File Write Error #1, Makino.csv
BI File Write Error #1, Makino.csv
BI File Write Error #1, Makino.csv
BI File Write Error #1, Makino.csv
BI File Write Error #1, Makino.csv
BI File Write Error #1, Makino.csv
BI File Write Error #1, Makino.csv
BI File Write Error #1, Makino.csv
BI File Write Error #1, Makino.csv
BI File Write Error #1, Makino.csv
BI File Write Error #1, Makino.csv
```

Comment: `tryCount = tryCount =+ 1` this is an invalid expression. It's either `tryCount = tryCount + 1` or `tryCount += 1`

Comment: Note that you should avoid using "bare" `except:` statements because they will catch _every_ possible exception, including those you aren't expecting, like syntax errors (which is probably what's happening here). Be specific about which one are being handled, or at least print or log the actual exception that has occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake on the following line:

```
tryCount = tryCount =+ 1
```

It should be:

```
tryCount += 1
```

Comment: `tryCount =+ 1` That is the same as `tryCount = +1`, which means "set tryCount to positive one".  It should be `+=`, not `=+`.

Comment: sorry,  John Gordon is right. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`tryCount = tryCount =+ 1` is in fact setting `tryCount` variable to be 1.

You need to do: `tryCount += 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
        tryCount = 0
        while tryCount < 5:
            try:
                with open(self.biFile, 'w') as o:
                    outputData.to_csv(o, header=True, index=False)
                tryCount = 5
            except:
                tryCount = tryCount =+ 1
                if tryCount < 5:
                    logEvent('BI File Write Error #'+ str(tryCount) + ', ' + os.path.basename(self.biFile), False)
                else:
                    logEvent('BI File Write Failed, ' + os.path.basename(self.biFile), False)
```

to

```
        for _ in range(5):
            try:
                with open(self.biFile, 'w') as o:
                    outputData.to_csv(o, header=True, index=False)
                break
            except:
                tryCount = tryCount =+ 1
                if tryCount < 5:
                    logEvent('BI File Write Error #'+ str(tryCount) + ', ' + os.path.basename(self.biFile), False)
                else:
                    logEvent('BI File Write Failed, ' + os.path.basename(self.biFile), False)
```